# ListTile Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

is there any way I can add more value to the ListTile in the code as I am trying to use ListTile to call the value of data in FireCloud. As for now, I can only call 2 of the data that is in the document. Any help would be much appreciated on how to call multiple data in FireCloud and display it.

```
    return Container(
     child: Card(
      child: ListTile(
       title: Text(widget.post.data["Address"]),
        subtitle: Image.network(widget.post.data["Picture"], 
     ),
   ),
 ),
);
```

Comment: not in list tile but you can create your own widget that can have multiple values using the Column and text widget as its children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this example that will work for you :

```
 ListView.builder(
            itemCount: /* snapshot.data.length */,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return  GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  //navigateToDetail(snapshot.data[index]),
                },
                              child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                     Text('your address'),
                     Text('you and another data')

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
          }),
```

You ca align it in the way you want.

Let me know if it works

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qhr2qFYA

Here is my full code for this ListView. I got the ListView builder in another widget, but this ListTile is in another widget.

Comment: just saw you code so what do you want I am confused , do you ant the listTile to have more information right.

Comment: Yes, so when i click the ListBuilder, it will navigate into the ListTile widget then view the content inside it.

Comment: check out the example that I have edited.Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ListView.builder constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html), this will help you fetch the total data from the `FireCloud`. You can use it like this:

Two major things required, these are:

- itemCount: Keeps the count of the data you are going to fetch from the `FireCloud`. Store the coming data into a list, and then pass it into this key
- itemBuilder: Builds your view which will have the data used from the passed item in the `itemCount`

*Reference:*

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: listItems.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index){
    // your_view
  }
)
```

For more reference, please refer to this Medium Article on how to get started: [Flutter: Displaying Content using ListView.builder](https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb)